# Is there a way to change JOptionPane.showMessageDialog font?

Tags: java, joptionpane

Is there a way to change the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` font? I'm trying to write code for a message dialog and I need to change the font if it's possible.

Comment: is it a input dialog ?

Comment: @Priyamal, no message dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 JOptionPane jopt = new JOptionPane();
    String result;
    result = "your message";
    JLabel resLabel = new JLabel(result);
    resLabel.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 50));
    jopt.showMessageDialog( null, resLabel, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
```

Create a new label with your custom font and set the jlabel as a component in joptionpane.

Comment: You may also want to look at `UIDefault.put` and set up `OptionPane.font` property to whatever font you want to use: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html for the list of UI properties overridden by Nimbus (this should also work with other LookAndFeel)