# Java, How come this text doesn't align in straight columns?

Tags: java, foreach, linked-list, alignment

So I want to be able to print out objects from a list in straight columns. The problem is that it won't align in straight columns. I want every parameter to padleft.

This is my result.

[image: Results]

I've tried using `String.format();` as you can see down below. It pads neither left nor right.

```
            String text = "";
            String text1 = "";



            for (Pet pet: h1.getPets()) {
                text = String.format("%-10s%10s%14s\n", pet.getName(), pet.getWeight() + "g", pet.getType());
                text1 += text;
            }

            String text2 = String.format("%s     %s     %s\n", "Namn:", "Vikt(gram):", "Djur:\n------------------------------------------");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text2 + text1, "HOTELLETS GÄSTER", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Comment: you must use a mono-spaced font for the dialog, see [Is there a way to change JOptionPane.showMessageDialog font?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36898533/85421) (or maybe use html for the text: [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) ) - more elaborate: use a `JTable` as message for the `JOptionPane`

Comment: Use a JTable. Your approach is only suitable for consoles with text in fixed-width fonts. It's not suitable for GUI's - use a real tabular structure. And a JOptionPane is probably not how you want to show this, you probably need to show this in a JFrame with a JScrollPane with a JTable inside the scroll pane.

Answer (score 0):

If i see that right, you have spaces in your format string:

```
"%s     %s     %s\n"
```

They will not align the "table" correctly. Try using the "tab"-symbol "\t":

```
"%s\t%s\t%s\n"
```

Comment: that part is only the headers, "Name:", "Weight:" and "Animal:".

It's `text1` that exist in the foreach loop that doesn't align in straight columns.